# Quick itemizing when pasting lists (in texstudio)

Tags: texstudio, itemize, ide

I do write scripts for teaching, so I frequently copy and paste from other sources to make itemized lists with snipptest of information seperated by a paragraph mark.

E.g.
snippet1
snippet2
snippet3

I would like to have a command/feature that wenn I paste and define it as a itemized list the `\itmem` command is placed in front of every paragraph/line.

E.g.

```
\begin{itemize}`
\item snippet1
\item snippet2
\item snippet3
\end{itemize}
```

just by pasting.

Granted, not the most pressing problem, but would save me some tedious work of always manually adding
`\item`

Thanks and best,
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the next script:

```
%SCRIPT
selected = cursor.selectedText(); 
items = new Array();
if (selected) {
  items = selected.split("\n");
  n = items.length;
} else {
  items[0] = ""; 
  n = 1;
}
editor.insertText("\\begin{itemize}\n");
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  editor.insertText("\\item "+items[i]+"\n");
}
editor.insertText("\\end{itemize}\n");
cursor.moveTo(cursor.lineNumber()-2,6);
cursor.removeSelectedText();
```

This puts an `\item` command in front of each of the selected rows.

Comment: Works great! Cheers!

Comment: How do you implement that?